# How do I restrict view instances with SimpleIoC (mvvm-light)

Tags: c#, mvvm-light, infragistics

I am just learning about MVVM-Light.  I have a WPF MDI application using Infragistics and MVVM-Light.  I have a XamRibbon with ButtonTool:

```
<igRibbon:ButtonTool Caption="Output Admin" 
                     igRibbon:RibbonGroup.MaximumSize="ImageAndTextLarge"
                     LargeImage="Images/calculate_32x32.png"
                     Click="OutputOnClick"/>
```

code behind:

```
    private void LoadWinContent(Window win, string paneMsg)
    {
        var sp = new SplitPane();
        var pane = new ContentPane
        {
            Header = paneMsg,
            Content = win.Content
        };
        sp.Panes.Add(pane);
        dockManager.Panes.Add(sp);
    }

    private void OutputOnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       if (!SimpleIoc.Default.ContainsCreated<OutputAdminViewModel>())
            LoadWinContent(new OutputAdmin(), "Test Output");
    }
```

In my "OutputOnCLick" event I test to see if the view has been created and if not I go ahead and load the view in the infragistics pane.  I do this so I don't have users making multiple panes of the same view.

When I close the pane and then click the OutputAdmin button, the view cannot be brought back up into a pane because of the logic I have on the OnClick event.

My questions are:  How do I close a pane and reset the view? Or "uncreate" it?  Is there a better way to handle this?

thanks